# What regex in Google Analytics to use for this case?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out what landing page regex to use to only show URLs that have only two sub-folders, e.g. see image below: just show green URLs but not the read ones as they have 3+ subfolders. Any advice on how to do this in GA with regex?

[image]

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
^\/[!#$&-;=?-[]_a-z~]+\/[!#$&-;=?-[]_a-z~]+\/$
```

The two sections contain all the valid html characters. We're also forcing the regex to start with slash, end with slash and have only one slash in between.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a path having only two components, e.g.

```
/component1/component2/
```

Then you may use the following regex:

```
/[^/]+/[^/]+/
```

### Demo

If your regex tool requires anchors, then add them:

```
^/[^/]+/[^/]+/$
```

Comment: Legend thanks, i tried playing around with regex and can't get this working: I want just URLs which contain /locate/ in the first path see screenshot: https://share.getcloudapp.com/X6uDQDvG how would i edit this: ^/[^/]+/[^/]+/$ (which works in GA)